# I need to display the list in the <table> as well as add row dynamically in Reactive form

Tags: angular, form-control, formarray, formgroups

In Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
<td>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.name" formControlName="item.name"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button (click)="addRow()">ADD Row </button>
</form>
```

Initially I have one data so I bind it in the text box. When I click Add button, I need to add empty text box row.

In component.ts

```
ngOninit(){
this.myform= formBuilder.group([
item.name : new FormControl('',Validators.Required);
]);
}
```

I have no idea how to use formArray in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To list the data in table
(Your HTML seems to be fine)

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td>
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.name" formControlName="item.name"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button (click)="addRow()">ADD Row </button>
</form>
```

**TS Code**

With this TS code, you Will be able to add a new row to the table and form control will be applied automatically.

```
addRow(){
items.push({'name' : ''});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
 <div formArrayName="properties">
  <div *ngFor="let prop of testForm.get('properties').controls; let i = index" >
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<br>
<button (click)="addFormField()">Add Field</button>
```

**Component**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class App {
  name:string;
  testForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      properties: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {  }

  addFormField() {
    <FormArray>this.testForm.get('properties').push(new FormControl());

  }

}
```

> After understanding the code steps try to add this in a table.

Comment: Thanks @Ashraful. I understand this snippet. I have one more doubt, Here you getting values from form array . Initially I have some data..I need to iterate over there. My assumption is , Initially we need to load those data in the formbuilder array which is in ngOnInit(). Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes you can do that